# Understanding output of lscpu

Tags: multithreading, cpu, processor, cpu-cores

You can see the output from `lscpu` command -

```
jack@042:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                56
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-55
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    14
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 79
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               2600.000
CPU max MHz:           2600.0000
CPU min MHz:           1200.0000
BogoMIPS:              5201.37
Virtualization:        VT-x
Hypervisor vendor:     vertical
Virtualization type:   full
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              35840K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-13,28-41
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     14-27,42-55
```

I can see that there are `2` sockets (which is like a processor ??) and inside each of the socket we have `14` cores. So, in total `2x14=28` physical cores. Normally, a CPU can contain multiple cores, so number of CPUs can never be smaller than number of Cores. But, as shown in the output `CPUs(s): 56` and this is what is confusing me.

I can see that Thread(s) per core:    2, so these 28 cores can behave like `2x28=56` logical cores.

**Question 1:** What does this `CPUs(s): 56` denote? Does `CPU(s)` denote number of Virtual/Logical cores, as it cannot be a Physical core atleast?

**Question 2:** What does this NUMA node mean? Does it represent the socket?

Answer (score 8):

([Copied](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/468791/86440) at the OP’s request.)

“CPU(s): 56” represents the number of logical cores, which equals “Thread(s) per core” × “Core(s) per socket” × “Socket(s)”. One socket is one physical CPU package (which occupies one socket on the motherboard); each socket hosts a number of physical cores, and each core can run one or more threads. In your case, you have two sockets, each containing a 14-core Xeon E5-2690 v4 CPU, and since that supports hyper-threading with two threads, each core can run two threads.

“NUMA node” represents the memory architecture; “NUMA” stands for [“non-uniform memory architecture”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access). In your system, each *socket* is attached to certain DIMM slots, and each physical CPU package contains a memory controller which handles part of the total RAM. As a result, not all physical memory is equally accessible from all CPUs: one physical CPU can directly access the memory it controls, but has to go through the other physical CPU to access the rest of memory. In your system, logical cores 0–13 and 28–41 are in one NUMA node, the rest in the other. So yes, one NUMA node equals one socket, at least in typical multi-socket Xeon systems.

Answer (score 5):

NUMA stands for Non-Uniform Memory Access. The value of NUMA nodes has to do with performance in terms of accessing the memory, and it's not involved in calculating the number of CPU's you have.

The calculation of 56 CPUs you are getting is based on

```
CPU's = number of sockets x number of cores per socket x number of threads per core
```

Here, 2 threads per core indicate that hyper-threading is enabled.

So, you don't have 56 physical processors, but rather a combination of sockets, cores and  hyper-threading. The bottom line is that you can run 56 threads in parallel. You can *think of* sockets to be equivalent of a physical processor.

-- edited based on the excellent comment by Margaret Bloom.

Comment: "Linux considers each thread of execution as a CPU" is deceiving: With SMT every OS will see 56 "CPUs". Granted that the term is ambiguous. "The bottom line is that you can run 56 instructions in parallel." is wrong. Cores is what count since the BE is shared between the two sibling HW threads and anyway x86 are superscalar so even a single thread can execute more than 1 inst/cycle. "You can think of sockets to be equivalent of a physical processor." is confusing but maybe not wrong. A socket is a number of cores + the uncore.

Comment: Thanks Jay. That's what I thought of it too.

Comment: @Jaywalker : how to get the 'Cores per Socket' value, when working with 'sysctl' command, I am working on Mac system. thank you

Answer (score 4):

**Threads per core:** A *hardware thread* is a sufficient set of registers to represent the current state of one software thread.  A core with two hardware threads can execute instructions on behalf of two different software threads without incurring the overhead of *context switches* between them. The amount of real parallelism that it can achieve will vary depending on what the threads are doing and, on the processor make and model.

**Cores per Socket:** A *core* is what we traditionally think of as a processor or a CPU, and a *socket* is the interface between one or more cores and the memory system.  A socket also is the physical connection between a chip or a multi-chip module and the main board.  In addition to the cores, a chip/module typically will have at least two levels of *memory cache*.  Each core typically will have its own *L1 cache*, and then all of the cores on the chip/module will have to share (i.e., compete for) access to at least one higher level cache and, to the main memory.

**Socket(s)**: see above.  Big systems (e.g., rack servers) often have more than one. Personal computers, less often.

**NUMA...:** I can't tell you much about [NUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access) except to say that communication between threads running on different NUMA nodes works differently from, and is more expensive than, communication between threads running on the same node.

Comment: Many thanks besmirched for your answer. Very appreciated :)